# Let $A=\{1,2,...,10\}$. Define $B_2=\{B\subseteq A: \vert B\vert =2\}$ Find $\vert B_2\vert.$

Tags: combinatorics

> Let $A=\{1,2,...,10\}$. Define $B_2=\{B\subseteq A: \vert B\vert =2\}$ Find $\vert B_2\vert.$

So I know there are $2^{10}$ total subsets but how do I compute the number of subsets of a specific size?

Comment: Are you looking for $B_2$ (i.e., find all the elements of $B_2$) or $|B_2|$ (i.e., the number of elements in $B_2$)?

Comment: How do you compute the number of subsets of a specific size?  This is **exactly** the problem that [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) are meant to answer.  There are $\binom{n}{k}$ subsets of size $k$ from an $n$ element set.  The set of subsets of size $k$ from an $n$ element set $A$ can also be notated $\binom{A}{k}$ if one desires.

Comment: $B_2$ is the set of all subsets of $A$ containing exactly two elements of A.

Comment: @kccu $\vert B_2 \vert$ I've fixed the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $10$ choices for one element of $B$ and $9$ for the other, so multiply those.

Then divide by $2$ because you have counted each possibility twice,

since the order of elements in a set doesn't matter.